# Cannot cast Snapshot Data as type Event

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, stream-builder

I am connecting to my Realtime database in Flutter. I am using a StreamBuilder to build the results fetched from the onValue listener on the database. Following the video linked [here](https://youtu.be/sXBJZD0fBa4?t=1987), at timestamp 33:07, it says to cast the snapshot data as Event. When I do this in my app I get the error

> The name 'Event' isn't a type, so it can't be used in an 'as' expression.

The only library it is hinting to import is the dart:html library, which is not what I want. I can't seem to find any other issues online associated with this.

Here is my code:

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: _database.child('searchTrends/google/').onValue,
    builder: (context, snapshot){

      final resList = <TrendCard>[];
      if(snapshot.hasData){
        final myResults = List<dynamic>.from(
            (snapshot.data! as Event).snapshot.value);

                // I then want to iterate through myResults.

      }else{
        return Center(child: Column(children: [CircularProgressIndicator()]));
      }
    }
),
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the current documentation for the [`onValue` stream](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/onValue.html), you'll see that the type it exposes is called a `DatabaseEvent`.

So:

```
final myResults = List<dynamic>.from(
    (snapshot.data! as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value);
```

I recommend always checking the actual product documentation if you get an error like this, as the APIs may have evolved since the tutorial was written.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to add as List at the end, like this..

```
                  final myResults = List<dynamic>.from(
                      (snapshot.data! as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value as List);
```

I was stuck with the same thing, but solved it eventually. Todd is using a map in the video, so add as Map at the end.

```
final myOrders = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
                      (snapshot.data! as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value
                          as Map);
```